Playwright Script Failing To Run on Docker in AWS Lambda but works Locally
I am trying to deploy an aws lambda function as a Docker image that runs playwright python. I am trying launch a browser with Firefox to do so.
            logger.info("Launching browser....")

            browser = p.firefox.launch(
                headless=False,
                args=args,
                proxy=proxy_creds,
            )

            logger.info("Setting context....")

            context = browser.new_context(
                base_url=auth_url,
                ignore_https_errors=True,
            )

I see the logs for Launching browser.... in the Cloudwatch console but not Setting context so it is failing to launch the browser. This all works locally on my mac.
Here is the Dockerfile with the image I am using:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.40.0-jammy-arm64 as build-image

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++ make cmake unzip libcurl4-openssl-dev

And the dependencies.
python = "^3.10"
boto3 = ">=1.28.3"
awswrangler = "3.5.2"
requests = "2.31.0"
pydantic = "2.0.3"
pyparsing = "^3.1.0"
pyjsparser = "^2.7.1"
fake-useragent = "1.2.1"
beautifulsoup4 = "4.12.2"
aws-lambda-powertools = "^2.28.1"
urllib3 = "^1.25.4"
playwright = "1.40.0"
importlib-metadata = "^7.0.2"
debugpy = "^1.8.1"
awslambdaric = "^2.0.10"

I expect this to run and launch a browser to navigate through web pages. I have tried chromium and I am able to launch a browser but after clicking login, the page always breaks before intercepting the response from a redirected request. The only browser I have been able to get the request is Firefox locally.
